# What filtering I could use to save my displacement data?

Tags: matlab, integration

I am double integrating my acceleration to obtain the displacement. However, the displacement looks so strange.

Basically this is the measured acceleration of a system under a impulse movement. and I am trying to obtain it's damping and stiffness properties from this experiment, and that why I would like to have the displacement data[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you have a DC offset to the acceleration data.  Try subtracting all acceleration by a constant until you get the first part of Velocity and Displacement to be a horizontal line.